# How to decode the received URL

Tags: node.js, swift, express

I've created the API sever by following these [Steps](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/#.WSvHoet96Ul).

And then I made an ios APP (swift3.0) to send HTTP request to it.

Because of the non-ASCII words in the url, I have to encode it before I send it.

But here comes a problem, I have no idea how to get it decoded at my API sever.

Is it possible to not encode the non-ASCII in swift, but also send the HTTP request?  (As I know, it is impossible by using NSMutableURLRequest(url: url))

Or where should I add the decoding code in my API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of the cases the way you encode anything answers the question: 'how to decode it?'.

As a rule, url is encoded using js method **encodeURI** or **encodeURIComponent**:

```
const link = http://google.com.ua
const encoded = encodeURIComponent(link)
const url = `http://yourrequest.com/api/${encoded}`
```

Some web servers decode it automatically, for example Express. In the case you need to do it manually there is another js method - decodeURIComponent:

```
const decoded = decodeURIComponent(link)
```

Comment: I've found out that there's no need for decoding. This API does it automatically. Thanks for the answer.